# rails include attachinary property as a relation in query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloudinary

I'm using [attachinary](https://github.com/assembler/attachinary) gem (1.3.0) to manage files in my rails 3 application. Assume that attachinary is bind to a model `Business` like

```
class Business < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attachment :logo
end
```

On a page I'm rendering ~30 business instances, and while optimizing my app, I've noticed that for every `business.logo` call new database query is made, so ~30 extra queries are made for each logo.
When I've tried to include logo in a businesses query, it failed because `logo` is not actually a relation.

```
Business.includes(:logo) # failed
```

How do I include attachinary as a relation to a query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

attachinary internally defines a relation, and then just wraps it to human readable `has_attachment` and `has_attachments`. what it actually does is (code is [here](https://github.com/assembler/attachinary/blob/master/lib/attachinary/orm/active_record/extension.rb#L8)):

```
relation = "#{options[:singular]}_files"
```

so you can access original relation with `logo_files` and add it to query like:

```
Business.includes(:logo_files)
```

no extra queries will be made, all entries will be joined to a query.
from instance it will still be accessible as `logo`:

```
business.logo
```

Comment: self-answered question in less than a minute? Are you trygin to get more reputation? Ahah

Comment: @MrYoshiji, not at all. I was unable to find answer to this question all over the internet, so I've decided to share the solution if somebody will be looking for it later to save their time, so I've posted q+a at one time.+ it does not seem to be a very popular problem that will gain my rep significantly